# Extremely Slow char* Access

Tags: arrays, c, performance, char

EDIT: SOLUTION

Instead of using a lookup table, I was able to group values so I could use a series of conditionals to select the value.

What was 3.702663s now takes 1.630996.

Taking it one step further with ranges in a switch statement the performance improved even more 3.759549s -> 1.013868s (3.7x improvement)

It is unclear why a lookup table would have caused a delay, but hopefully I figure that out as I prefer the table.

---

Maybe I've looked at it too many times or I'm overlooking something really stupid, but no matter what I change, I run into the same issue. The issue is that accessing `buffer` should be constant time, but if I use the variable `third` instead of `first` as the index in `table`, it takes almost 2x the time to process the file. It occurs with any size file.

(test.txt can be created by filling a file with bytes <= 0x40)

Timing for 1GB file.

```
$ gcc -O2 -o test test.c && ./test && rm test
2.0287s
3.7871s
```

Any ideas?

(I've written this to demonstrate the issue, and yes, it's useless beyond that)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static const uint8_t table[64] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
};

#define RUN(variable)                                                          \
    idx = 0;                                                                   \
    first = buffer[idx];                                                       \
    second = buffer[idx];                                                      \
    next = idx + table[second];                                                \
    third = buffer[next];                                                      \
    start = clock();                                                           \
    while (idx < length) {                                                     \
        first = second;                                                        \
        second = third;                                                        \
        idx = next;                                                            \
        next += table[variable];                                               \
        third = (next < length) ? (buffer[next]) : 0;                          \
    }                                                                          \
    end = clock();                                                             \
    printf("%fs\n", (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

int main() {
    uint8_t first, second, third;
    size_t idx, next, length;
    clock_t start, end;

    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    char* buffer;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    fread(buffer, 1, length, file);
    fclose(file);
    RUN(first);
    RUN(third);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: No macro, separate start/end

```
gcc -O2 -o test test.c && ./test && rm test
1.9776s
3.6817s
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


static const uint8_t table[64] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
};

int main() {
    uint8_t first, second, third;
    size_t idx, next, result, length;
    clock_t start1, end1, start2, end2;

    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    char* buffer;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    fread(buffer, 1, length, file);
    fclose(file);

    // Using variable 'first' and {start,end}1
    idx = 0;
    first = buffer[idx];
    second = buffer[idx];
    next = idx + table[second];
    third = buffer[next];
    start1 = clock();
    while (idx < length) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        idx = next;
        next += table[first];
        third = (next < length) ? (buffer[next]) : 0;
    }
    end1 = clock();
    printf("%fs\n", (float)(end1 - start1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // Using variable 'third' and {start,end}2
    idx = 0;
    first = buffer[idx];
    second = buffer[idx];
    next = idx + table[second];
    third = buffer[next];
    start2 = clock();
    while (idx < length) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        idx = next;
        next += table[third];
        third = (next < length) ? (buffer[next]) : 0;
    }
    end2 = clock();
    printf("%fs\n", (float)(end2 - start2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);


    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Get rid of the macro and just write C code. Let the optimizer figure that out.

Comment: This code is really jumbled up and doesn't make a lot of sense. What is doing?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just measuring the time from start in both cases, and the second call includes the first's time?

Comment: @tadman The macro is for readability here, I'm not actually using a macro in the real code. In this example it is reading a char in the buffer and then jumps to the next char by the value retrieved from table. However I've made them all 1 for simplicity here. Correct, I am not measuring the two together. This can be checked by commenting out the macro for one and running them independently

Comment: The real question is, why would 'third' take longer than 'first'. Regardless of the rest of the code, both of them are uint8_t and both are being used in the exact same way.

Comment: The macro makes this extremely un-readable. It's a wreck in its current form.

Comment: This takes 0.002s to do a 1MB file. How big a file are you reading?

Comment: @tadman macro removed in edit. This timing is for a 1GB file

Comment: This thing looks like it skips around a lot given some kinds of data, iterating through the whole file, and in other cases stopping early because it popped out of bounds. It could go in a really long loop. What this thing does is completely opaque.

Comment: There's a high probability that this algorithm, whatever it is, just takes longer to complete it's bizarre dance when using `third` as a seed.

Comment: New version just segfaults.

Comment: @tadman I don't understand how that could be, the lookup on buffer is using a uint as the index, which is already known prior to using it as the index. The only difference is "table[first]" vs "table[third]"

Comment: @tadman fixed, the filename had accidentally been updated

Comment: What you need is one function that you can call multiple times, not a bunch of code that's all mixed up. `first`, `second` etc. has to go. I'd use `int values[3]` and shuffle them up as you do, passing in an index parameter to select which to use.

Comment: @tadman right, this is not production code. It in fact uses an inline function and all the values are members of a struct. The code is far more complicated than I can post here, also for other reasons it can't be posted. The only difference that causes an issue is when 'third' is used instead of 'first'.

Comment: There has to be some undefined behaviour here because it's not behaving consistently.

Comment: `next = idx + table[second];` <<-- are you sure that second in less than 64 ?

Comment: @wildplasser yes, this implementation reads a file with bytes < 64 so the lookup will always be <64 when using the byte value for the index.

Comment: I just dont understand why you are trying to optimise a nonsensical program.

Comment: @wildplasser as I mentioned in my original question, it is nonsensical in this form, but not in the actual form. I extracted specific code for this question that replicates the issue.

Comment: Since you are fiddling with the `idx` inside the loops, maybe the second firm just execustes more loops. Try adding a counter inside both loops.

Comment: @tadman There is definitely some weird behavior. I added a size_t var xyz and have "xyz += table[third]" in both cases and it didn't increase the timing when using "first" like I would have expected.

Comment: The line `third = (next < length) ? (buffer[next]) : 0;` is the problem. It doesn't make any sense, but neither does this code. I've [cleaned it up](https://gist.github.com/tadman/fe41bd68bcf7decad136e83f19a6dbe6) and it's still bizarrely broken.

Comment: I added `assert(keys[2] == 0)` since I'm using an all 0 byte file and the problem goes away. This is just bizarre.

Comment: @tadman I stopped using the lookup table and was able to group values so I could use a conditional. It's not great, but it works and cut the time significantly (3.702663s -> 1.630996s)

Comment: It's actually 3.7s -> 1.3s

Comment: Switch+ranges = 3.759549s -> 1.013868s (3.7x improvement)

Answer (score 4):

In the line :

```
third = (next < length) ? (buffer[next]) : 0;
//       1 < 64 ? 64 : 0;
```

With your example at the first pass third = 64 which goes to outside the table array in the next loop :

```
next += table[third]; // table[64]
```

Comment: With a 1gb file, this would be: get char in buffer up to length-1 if uint 'next' is less than 1024*1024*1024.